# Rewrite $u_m=(e_m^T A v)^k, \, m=1,\ldots, n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $e_m$ be standard basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be positive definite matrix, and $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now let  vector $u$ be defined as 
\begin{align}
u_m=(e_m^T A v)^k, \, m=1,\ldots, n
\end{align} 
where $k$ is some positive integer.

**Question:** Can the above expression be re-written in some other equivalent form? Specifically, can we re-write the about in terms $u$ and not individual coordinates of $u$.

Comment: For the (trivial) case of $k=1$, one has $u_m=e_m^\top A v\implies u=Av$. Hence your desired $u$ for larger $k$ corresponds to performing element-wise multiplication of $Av$ with itself $k$ times. In linear algebra, this operation goes under the name "Hadamard product" and is denoted with $\circ$ (e.g. $A\circ B$). So yours would be $u=(Av)\circ (Av)\circ\cdots \circ (Av)=(Av)^{\circ n}$. So the question is whether there's any convenient identities in this vein.

Comment: @Semiclassical  Just to clarify. You saying that for $k>1$,  $u_m=(e^TAv)^k$ is the same as   $u=(Av)^{ \circ k}$, right?

Comment: Woops, yes. Good catch.